# R:Error in normalizePath(key$InstallPath, mustWork = FALSE, winslash = "/")

Tags: r

When i try to install a package from github by these codes:

```
library(devtools)
devtools::install_github('bbc/bbplot')
```

R shows the error:

```
Error in normalizePath(key$InstallPath, mustWork = FALSE, winslash = "/") : 
  file name conversion problem -- name too long?
```

My R version is:
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32
arch           x86_64
os             mingw32
system         x86_64, mingw32
status
major          3
minor          6.3
year           2020
month          02
day            29
svn rev        77875
language       R
version.string R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
nickname       Holding the Windsock

This error showed everytime as i    installed package from GitHub except CRAN.